# AWS API SDK provides invalid URL

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I created an API using AWS and generated the SDK for iOS use. However, when I try to call the API, I get this error.

```
Error occurred: Error
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1546a36b0{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)https://(api-path),...}
```

The URL is hard-coded in the SDK and does not have any sort of (null) in the string. I have no clue where this is coming from.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? Which the iOS SDK version you are using? Was the generated SDK for objC or Swift?

Comment: My n-month old app: today, it's getting same message. This maybe an issue for Amazon to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the following code in the AWS-generated `init(configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration)` worked for me:

Original:

```
if let endpoint = configuration.endpoint {
    self.configuration.baseURL = endpoint.URL
}
```

Replace by:

```
self.configuration.baseURL = URL(string: URLString)
```

I don't understand why it says the endpoint is nil even though it has successfully been created immediately beforehand. Anyway, it might help you solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `NSURL` object to see if it is nil when you init it from `NSString`.

Then check your url in `NSString` to see if it contains any white spaces, which make your url invalid.

To solve that you have to add this to your url:

```
NSString *yourUrl; // Your url in NSString type.
NSString *encoded = [substring stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encoded];
```

**To those who downvoted my answer:**

If you downvoted because it wasn't written in swift, I just tried my best to help.

Just because I don't have experience with swift programming, doesn't mean I have to stop helping others to solve their problems.